# Java Static Values Not Outputting Decimals "Possible lossy conversion from double to int"

Tags: java

Hello I'm very new to java only 3 days in and I'm struggling for this program to output in decimals.

```
static int temp1=66-32*(5/9);

static int temp2=95-32*(5/9);

static int temp3=85-32*(5/9);

static int temp4=65-32*(5/9);

static int temp5=(0-32)*(.55);


public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("Today's temperature is 66 degrees Fahrenheit.  In Celsius it is:"+temp1);
   System.out.println("The temperature is 95 degress Fahrenheit in Celsius is:"+temp2);
   System.out.println("The temperature is 85 degrees Fahrenheit in Celsius is:"+temp3); 
   System.out.println("The temperature is 65 degrees Fahrenheit in Celsius is:"+temp4);
   System.out.println("The temperature is 0 degrees Fahrenheit in Celsius is:\n"+temp5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`5/9 == 0` in integer division as 5 divided by 9 gives you nothing with 5 remainder.

Your formula is also incorrect. You need to perform the `-32` first.

```
int temp1 = (66-32) * 5 / 9;
```

This will give you the closest integer value rounded down.

```
double temp1 = (66 - 32) * 5 / 9.0;
// print temp1 to two decimal places.
System.out.printf("Temp1= %.2f%n", temp1);
```

This will give you two decimal places. The use of `/ 9.0` means that floating point division is used as `9.0` is a double value. Up to this point it makes little difference but you could have written.

```
double temp1 = (66.0 - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;
```

and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**, if you want to receive output in decimals, you will have to change the data types from `int` to `double`, because `double` is the data type used to declare variables as holding a decimal value. So change all the `int`'s to `double`'s.

**Second**: You think (5/9) should output something like 0.555, right? Because that's what you get when you punch it into a calculator. But no! In Java, (5/9) is calculated as an INTEGER conversion, because 5 and 9 are both INTEGERS. That means, when Java calculates (5/9), it returns only the number left of the decimal point, because it knows not to deal with decimals. What's the number left of the decimal point in 0.555? Obviously, 0. So the answer returned for (5/9) will be 0, and that means your `temp1`, `temp2`, `temp3`, and `temp4` will all be 0, since 0 multiplied by anything is 0. For `temp5`, you included the decimal point in .55 - therefore, this calculation is fine.

**So... what?** If you want a decimal answer printed on the screen, you can do 1 of 2 things: Add a decimal point to the end of every number. So make it `66.0-32.0 * (5.0/9.0)`. OR, you could simply add a `(double)` cast to the (5/9). So something like this: `((double)5/9)`. Make sure that you format it EXACTLY as given, or it won't work and you might still get 0. Here is the finished code below:

```
public class printDecimal{
    static double temp1 = 66-32 * ((double)5/9);
    static double temp2 = 95-32 * ((double)5/9);
    static double temp3 = 85-32 * ((double)5/9);
    static double temp4 = 65-32 * ((double)5/9);
    static double temp5 = (0-32) * ((double)5/9);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("66 degrees Fahrenheit in Celsius is: "+temp1);
        System.out.println("95 degrees Fahrenheit in Celsius is: "+temp2);
        System.out.println("85 degrees Fahrenheit in Celsius is: "+temp3);
        System.out.println("65 degrees Fahrenheit in Celsius is: "+temp4);
        System.out.println("0 degrees Fahrenheit in Celsius is: "+temp5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using Integers. Integers can not show decimals. Try to use double instead. Double gives you up to 16 digits of precision.

```
static double yourTemp = ...
```

Comment: double gives you up to 16 digits of precision which could be more than 16 decimal places.

Comment: You can correct your answer and I will delete my comment.